# Google Reader - > create tweets, push to mysql database

Tags: php, twitter, google-reader

I need to be able to create tweets from shared items on google reader (like reader2twitter does) and then push them for storage in a MySQL database.

I know that the shared feed from reader is an atom feed, but beyond that, not even sure where to start.  Can someone please point me to some resources, or tips on how I would even go about doing this?

Thanks in advance, as always!

Comment: i was looking around and i could theoretically push the shared items feed through feedburner to generate rss;  but then how do i get the rss data into the database?  and then parse and shorten it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to your Comment, stating that you could consolidate your Shared Items Feed to create a new RSS Feed, you could then use [MagpieRSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) to fetch and parse that RSS Feed and interact with your Database.

To trigger the MagpieRSS Parser, you would either need a Cron Job, or a Scheduled Task (dependent on your server infrastructure). Otherwise, you may be able to use Feedburner to send you Emails, and then [Pipe those Emails to your Script](http://wiki.jumba.com.au/wiki/Pipe_an_email_to_a_script) to parse the content again.